# os.listdir() crashes when used with several thousands of files

Tags: python, listdir, oserror

I'm downloading a dataset full of `json` files which are expected to be read and merged at the end in order to prepare a training set for a predictive model. Whenever I run `os.listdir()` in a folder with less than 60-70.000 files (while they are downloading) I typically get a list of them and I'm able to sequentially load them into memory for the merging part. When this number exceeds the threshold that I've mentioned I get the following error;

```
/usr/lib/python3.7/pathlib.py in _select_from(self, parent_path, is_dir, exists, scandir)
    523     def _select_from(self, parent_path, is_dir, exists, scandir):
    524         try:
--> 525             with scandir(parent_path) as scandir_it:
    526                 entries = list(scandir_it)
    527             for entry in entries:

OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error: '../../data/power/tables/walking_activity'
```

Although I've used os functions in the past for image datasets, this kind of error has never popped up before. Do you know what could be the case?

Comment: your machine can't hold all that data in memory, perhaps because you are using lots of memory in other parts of your code? this is hard to answer without more information. try using `os.scandir` which returns an iterator instead of a list

Comment: Do you really need to store whole output of `os.listdir(...)` ? if not, use a generator equivalent with `pathlib.Path.iterdir`

Comment: @thomask: Sadly, `pathlib.Path.iterdir` is implemented in terms of `os.listdir`, not `os.scandir`. Most of the wrappers that claim to operate lazily (e.g. `glob.iglob`, `Path.iterdir`) actually operate eagerly (even if they use `scandir` under the hood; some parts of `pathlib` do, but they `list`ify the `scandir` iterator immediately before continuing processing), then lazily filter or wrap the results.